# Finding value of $\int\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

> Finding value of $\displaystyle \int\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Try: let $$I=\int\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\bigg[\frac{\ln x}{1-ix}+\frac{\ln x}{1+ix}\bigg]dx$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\ln x}{1-ix}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\ln x}{1+ix}dx$$

Put $1+ix =t$ Then $dx=-idt$ and $1-ix=u$ Then $dx=idu$

So $$I=\frac{i}{2}\int \frac{\ln(1-u)-\ln(i)}{u}du-\frac{-i}{2}\int \frac{\ln(1-t)-\ln(i)}{t}dt$$

Could some help me to solve it , Thanks

Comment: this very much does not have an answer in terms of elementary functions. Are you looking for a derivation in terms of special functions?

Comment: Yes qbert i am also looking for special fubction.

Comment: You cannot find *the value* of an indefinite integral. You can write an antiderivative for $\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}$ in terms of the dilogarithm function $\text{Li}_2$ and this has already been asked an answered many times on MSE.

Comment: Yes jack DAurizio . How to write in Dilogarithm function $\Li_{2}$ form.

Comment: Use Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(log(x)%2F(1%2Bx%5E2),x).

Comment: $\int \frac{\ln (x)}{1+x^2} \, dx=\tan ^{-1}(x) \ln (x)-\frac{1}{4} x \Phi \left(-x^2,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)+C$ where : $\Phi (x,y,z)$ is Lerch transcendent function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\ln(x)+C=\int\frac1x{\rm~d}x$$

and

$${\rm Li}_2(x)+C=\int\frac{\ln(1-x)}x{\rm~d}x$$

where ${\rm Li}$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), since

$${\rm Li}_1(x)=\ln(1-x)$$

and

$${\rm Li}_{s+1}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{{\rm Li}_s(t)}t{\rm~d}t$$

Comment: Hey. What is your discord ID? Tell me, or invite me @ Vidyanshu#6092

Comment: Have something to discuss with you.

Comment: Check like the first line of my profile page lol.

Comment: Nah but it takes me to discord server not to your profile.

Comment: You'll find me there. >_>

Answer (score 1):

we know that $$\ln(x)+C=\int\frac1x{\rm~d}x$$
also

$${\rm Li}_2(x)+C=\int\frac{\ln(1-x)}x{\rm~d}x$$

$${\rm Li}_1(x)=\ln(1-x)$$

also
$${\rm Li}_{s+1}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{{\rm Li}_s(t)}t{\rm~d}t$$

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]